# Ampere's law, do I include the electric field causing the current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics

Let's say I have a long, straight wire with a time varying current, $I$ through it. Now if I take a circular Amperian path around this loop wire (and concentric with it) there is both a current $I$ through the loop but also the time varying electric field, call it $E$ which is causing the current to flow. DO I need to include both this electric field and the current in Ampere's law (with Maxwell's addition) or does the current take care of the electric field?